# How to display mysql database tables and their respective column names

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have several tables in a mysql database called automobile.

In database.php below,i loop through all tables in the database and display them.I pass an  element inside each table that once cliked leads to  table_fields.php

database.php

```
<ul class = "list-group">

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

echo"<p class = 'jumbotron'>Table List</p>";



$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("automobile") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("show tables");


while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // go through each row that was 
 returned in $result

 echo"<li class='list-group-item'>";
 echo"<a href= 'table_fields.php'>";

 echo $table[0]. "<BR>";    // print the table that was returned on that row.

 echo "</a>";
 echo "</li>";

}
?>
```

In table_fields .php below,i have created a script that displays columns from the first table.The table name is 'amin'.

table_fields.php

```
<html>

<head>

<script src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "form.js"></script>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="bootstrap.min.css" >



</head>

<body class = "container">

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("automobile")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "select * from amin";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table class ='table table-striped table-bordered' style ='width:100%'>";
echo "<tr>";

for ( $i = 0; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {
  $columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);

  echo "<th>".$columnnames. "</th>";

 }


   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</table>";
  ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

As you have probably noticed the code in table_fields.php displays columns from 'amin' table only yet it is referenced by all  elements in database.php.Therefore no matter which table i click i see columns for 'amin' table.

My question is how do i pass table name into code logic so that each table in table_fields.php file displays its respective columns and not columns from the amin table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the table name to the `table_fields.php` file as an argument. The easiest way to do this as a query string parameter.

```
echo '<a href="table_fields.php?table=' . $table[0] . '">' . $table[0] . '</a>';
```

Then in your `table_fields.php` file, you can access the table name using `$table = $_GET['table'];`.

I would however suggest being **very careful** to not use unsanitized input from the URL. So you should use prepared PDO statements, and **NOT** use the `mysql` functions.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate with a working example based on my code ?

Comment: Will @fubar get the pay and or class credits if he does?  Work on it, if you are blocked, post another question.